Am I allowed to log request's remote IP address and city?
I wanted to ask if I'm allowed to keep information about the IP address and country with city in the logs (retention time: 7 days)?
Example below:
2024/09/24 06:07:14 {"endpoint":"/users","method":"POST","status":422,"message":"body is in incorrect format","duration":"85.043078ms","host":"127.0.0.1","location":{"country":"Canada", "city": "Toronto"},"agent":"insomnia/10.0.0"}

My reasoning for that is that my service heavily depends on where's user from to update language and block access to certain parts of the service based on the user's country. However, I do live in Germany and I'm not sure if it's allowed in regards to GDPR. I'm logging it for debugging and maintenance purposes (to fix potential issues). I'm a solo dev so I'm the only one who's got access to these logs.

You are processing personal data, so you need a legal basis for that. If the processing is strictly necessary to fulfill your legal obligations or to carry out your users request, that is your legal basis. However, debugging and maintenance purposes seems only indirectly relevant. Otherwise, the legal basis available to you would be legitimate interest.
To use this legal basis, you need to weigh up your own interest in logging this data compared to the user's expectations of privacy. Relevant questions are whether you'd expect the users to mind were you to ask them, whether there is any risk of their interests being harmed, etc. IP addresses being logged is common, so making the case isn't difficult here. It also works in your favour that you have a short data retention period and very restricted access to it.
To dot the i's, write down a short document where you spell out how you've done this weighing up of interests and concluded that it is fine.

It's a good idea to not answer questions that ask for legal advice, as they will be closed.
